# In Eclipse , how to view a GridView Using a Button

Tags: java, eclipse

In Eclipse , how to view a GridView Using a Button , knowing that gridview returning data from database , i did actually all the code , except the code inside the button ..! is there any method to view simple gridview by using a button .... ill be thankfull

Comment: Please mention that which UI you are using.

Comment: Is this Android? Eclipse supports many UI toolkits and if you don't say which one you are using you are unlikely to get much help

Comment: Are you developing an eclipse plugin using SWT/Swing/JavaFx? @Shruti +1

Comment: I develop Android Applications using Eclipse Java JPA J2SE 5.0   and for the UI I use XML activities ,